# How is Yajnavalkya an enlightened soul in Ramayana, but still a student in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, vyasa, yajnavalkya

The conversation between Yajnavalkya and Janaka is very famous. Yajnavalkya instructs Janaka, which seems to imply he is already learnt and not a student anymore.

But Vyasa's disciple is Vaishampayana and his discipline is Yajnavalkya, and he famously learns Shukla Yajurveda directly from Lord Surya. So he was still a student during Mahabharata.

How can this be reconciled? Were there many Yajnavalkyas as this [source](https://ithihas.wordpress.com/2019/08/06/yajnavalkya-father-of-hindu-philosophy/amp/) claims?

> Date of Yajnavalkya
>
> In Valmiki’s Ramayana, one Yajnavalkya Vajasaneyi is mentioned as a
> contemporary of Janaka who gave his daughter in marriage to Rama of
> Ayodhya. In Bhagavata Purana another Yajnavalkya is mentioned as
> learning Yoga from Hiranyanabhah who was the seventeenth in descent
> from Rama of Ayodhya.13 In Mahabharata we find one Yajnavalkya rishi
> assisting the great sage Vyasa as adhvaryu priest in the Rajasuya
> ceremony performed by Yudhisthira. In Vishnu Purana the disciple of
> Vaishampayana, Yajnavalkya is said to be the son of Vishnurata while
> Yajnavalkya of the Shukla Yajur Veda is said to be the son of
> Vajasaneyi Devarata.14 All these indicates that many Yajnavalkyas
> lived at different times and that Yajnavalkya like Janaka is the title
> or surname of a class and not the name of an individual. Except on
> such a hypothesis, all the facts in reference to Yajnavalkya and other
> rishis and Janaka and similar other kings cannot be reconciled.

Comment: Could you pls share either references or verbatim both conversations so that your conclusions can be ascertained? Thank you.

Comment: It is not the same Janaka.

Comment: @sbharti it's very famous in Hinduism, everyone knows that.

Comment: @sbharti https://upanishads.org.in/stories/the-light-of-the-lights

Comment: @sbharti https://www.google.com/amp/s/hridayaravinde.wordpress.com/2019/12/01/vaishampayan-yajnavalkya/amp/

Comment: @sbharti https://ithihas.wordpress.com/2019/08/06/yajnavalkya-father-of-hindu-philosophy/amp/

Comment: Who has voted to close thus question for the sake of clarity. What clarity do you need??

Comment: Would you have a better source than a blog? You have claimed they are in Ramayan and Mahabharat but you've quoted a blog. Thank you.

Comment: @sbharti I didn't mean its there in Valmiki Ramayana. But the story of Vajnavalkya and Gargi's debate before Janaka is well known. Look https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargi_Vachaknavi

Comment: @sbharti and the blog is of vwry good quality, all main claims are referenced. Please scroll down there are references at the end.

Comment: The entire line of kings is known as Janaka not only The Maharaja from Ramayana. Current Valmiki doesn’t have mention of Yajnavalkya.